# Finding all pair of points with the same distance to a line in O(nlogn)

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I am trying to solve an algorithm problem. I have 2 arrays, say A and B, containing some points. Length of A and B are the same. I know that all points in A and B are distinct. Now, I want to find all the pairs with the same distance to a line. There is also one more rule. I cannot compare 2 points both in A and both in B.

How can I solve this problem in O(nlogn)? I think this is a divide and conquer problem, but I could not find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: An example:

```
Line -> y=0
A = {(1,2), (3,4)}
B = {(1,-2), (3,-4)}
Output -> {{(1,2), (1,-2)}, {(3,4), (3,-4)}}
```

EDIT2: Assume that all distances are also distinct.

Comment: I don't understand the significance of having two arrays? As far as I understand, you have a bucket of points, and a line, and you want to group the points into sub-buckets based on their distance to the given line, such that two points are in the same sub bucket iff their distance to the line is that same?

Comment: Two array is the input of the program. The output is pairs of one point from A and one point from B.

Comment: Can you illustrate with an example?

Comment: OK, starting to get a picture of it now. Still some questions remain. E.g. how is the line represented as an input to the program?

I agree with @KaidulIslam- an example would help. And the exact signature of the function: parameters & return type.

Comment: Actually, representations are not so important. I just want to know the algorithm to find the solution.

Comment: Another question. Suppose there are two points in A that have distance 5 from the line and also two points in B with that distance. Should this result in 4 pairs or 2 pairs? E.g. should we return just (a1, b1) and (a2, b2) or should we also return (a1, b2) and (a2, b1)?

Comment: @JohnColeman from a purely techincal point I agree, but my intuition tells me that each pair should only be considered once- based on the nlogn stipulation...

Comment: Why not just sort the points by distance from the line?

Comment: @ColmBhandal Assume that distances are also distinct.

Comment: @Henry The only comparison we can make is comparing the distances of one point from A and one point from B.

Comment: @qwerty can't think of a solution that doesn't use sorting & it's not very clear from the question what you can and can't do. Maybe if you gave more context to the problem e.g. why you don't want to sort, we'd understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is esoteric *(prohibition of comparing two points looks silly here)* variant of **nuts and bolts** problem. O(NlogN) solution might use quicksort-like partition:

Make comparison function like this:

```
float Compare(int A_Index, int B_Index)
   return Distance(line, A[A_Index]) - Distance(line, B[B_Index])
```

Choose random index `a_idx` from A.  Partition B array using Compare with `a_idx`. Resulting pivot `B[b_idx]` corresponds to `A[a_idx]` element. Now partition array A against `b_idx`. You have a pair of equal elements and left and right subarrays of points with smaller and larger distances.

Repeat for both halves of arrays until all points are paired.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Why not an `O(n)` routine? Hash the distance from each point in A to Line:

```
Distance 1 -> {A[0]}
Distance 2 -> {A[1]}
```

Iterate over B and if the distance from `B[i]` to Line has already been hashed, add `B[i]` to make a pair:

```
Distance 1 -> {A[0], B[0]}
Distance 2 -> {A[1], B[1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

A hash table (`std::unordered_map`) which was keyed on the distance, would have a feature of N insertions of order O(1).  However, if there was a collision with the key it would break the constraint of comparing 2 A elements.

Searching the hash table for elements in B would also be O(1).  So the performance would be O(N) - but I can't see how to avoid the collision case.

Comment: OP said assume all distances are distinct, I'm guessing in any one list (last line in the question).